# mergPopActivity from mergExt use in android with livecode

Tags: livecode

Anyone have use the mergPopActivity in the Android to share text for Facebook or something else?
Is there any example how we use it?

This is from mergExt

```
on mouseUp
   try
      mergPopActivity "Hello"
   catch e
      answer e
   end try
end mouseUp
```

Answer (score 0):

The *mergAndroid.html* contains the following information about  mergPopActivity:

```
command mergPopActivity pText,pImagePaths,pURLs
```

Share data to other apps

Parameters:

```
pText - A string that you want to share. 
Note that the Facebook app has a bug that it will not accept shared text.

pImagePaths - A list of image paths to share. The image paths must be readable by other applications such as on external storage

pURLs - A list of URLs to include in the share text.
```

Comment: thank you and i have see the mergAndroid.html ,but i don't see any info or example code How we use it.the demo is no working but i figure out a fix for this..the only question is..The demo show up a modal window with contact in first field,the field to put some text and send button.how we pass the text or something else in the facebook?we need to have installed the facebook app in the mobile?i just try to figure out HOW we pass info from mergPopActivity..